# How to make 5 cards on each line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-flex-layout

Can someone help me please?

I'm writing in Angular and I want to display for example 5 cards on each row. Now I have horizontal scroll, and it looks like that:
[image]

Code:

```
<div class="content">
    <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" style="width: 35%; ">
  
        <!-- Single "Responsive" Card-->
        <div fxFlex [style.margin]="'20px'" style="display: flex;">
            <mat-card *ngFor="let release of releases" [style.min-width]="'200px'">
                <mat-card-header>
                    <mat-card-title>{{release.name}}</mat-card-title>
                    <mat-card-subtitle>New Release</mat-card-subtitle>
                </mat-card-header>
                <a href='/album'><img  mat-card-image class="album-cover" src={{release.images[0].url}} alt="album art"></a>
                <strong>Release Date: </strong>{{release.release_date}}<br />
                <strong>Tracks: </strong>{{release.total_tracks}}<br /><br />
                <a style="text-decoration:none" href="/artist">
                <mat-card-content *ngFor="let rel of release.artists">
                    <mat-chip-list aria-label="Artist selection">
                        <mat-chip>{{rel.name}}</mat-chip>
                        
                    </mat-chip-list>

                </mat-card-content>
            </a>
            </mat-card>
        </div>
```

How can I display 5 cards on each row for example? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solution lies in using the right styles.
If you are looking to have few cards on each row, you might have to use max-width on the container containing the cards.

Comment: Doesn't work ((

Answer (score 0):

it because you wrap all with `style: flex` . to fix this you can add this style for child element in this case it `mat-card`

```
style = flex: 20%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your styles are a bit messy...

First: I recommend separating styling from html, use css files

Second: cards doesnt get wrapped because you specify `fxLayout="row wrap"` on `mat-card's grandparent`, but it cannot `wrap` anything because it only has one child, if you want to use flexbox then `flex-flow: row wrap;` must be declared on `mat-card's` direct `parent div`, and plus `mat-card` must have `max-width: 20%`.

But i would use `grid`, just remove every styling from html and add `display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat (5, 1fr);` to the div that contains mat-cards
this will automatically devide each row in 5 containers of equal width and wrap the other ones to next row, you dont need to add anything else.

If you want it to be mobile frindly, you just add media query and change `repeat(5,1fr)` to `repeat(1fr)` and it will show one card in each row, when reproduced in mobile